# Send data to and handle response data from specific client / connection - Node.js - Net socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

Using this code I can receive data initiated by the client so far so good. The client let's the connection open and will reconnect when the connection is broken.

Sometimes I wan't to send data to a **specific** client during this open connection for example every 5 minutes. So I need a timer (that's not the problem) and the code for sending data to a **specific** client.

```
// Client array
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

    // Add client to array
    clients.push(socket);

    socket.on('data', function (buffer) {
        // Handle incomming Data 
    });

    socket.on('end', function () {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        // Client disconnect
    });

}).listen(5055);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can I send data to a **specific** client.

Comment: You have a list of clients, you pick up a client from that list and call the `write()` or `end()` methods. Maybe I'm missing something?